# Disabling concurrent execution of tests

Tags: maven, testing, concurrency

We have a few people working on a single project. In the test enviroment we use sandboxes of real services, that can be accessed only by one machine at a time (if you run tests on the same time on 2 machines tests will fail). Is there a way to lock execution of certain tests on a machine if they are currently running on another one? We use maven and have tests split into unit and integration tests. The ideal solution would be to lock only the execution of integration tests.

I'd be grateful for any tips.

Answer (score 0):

Imho you should delegate integration test execution to a Continuous integration server and disable its on dev profile.
 I don't think there is a way to do what you're expecteing except by locking the target resource and test the lock programaticaly in integration test implementation